# Segmentation fault in gst_mini_object_init

Tags: c, debugging, gstreamer

I'm trying to use Gstreamer in a C program.

I use `udpsrc` so I have to put caps :

```
GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_new_empty_simple("application/x-rtp");
```

With this, I get an **Segmentation fault**.

So, I've tried with `G_DEBUG="fatal_warnings" gdb --args ./test_gst`.
Here's the output :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76f010e4 in gst_mini_object_init (mini_object=0x28600, flags=0, type=0, copy_func=0x76ed6174 <_gst_caps_copy>, dispose_func=0x0, free_func=0x76ed5128 <_gst_caps_free>)
    at gstminiobject.c:133
133 gstminiobject.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76f010e4 in gst_mini_object_init (mini_object=0x28600, flags=0, type=0, copy_func=0x76ed6174 <_gst_caps_copy>, dispose_func=0x0, free_func=0x76ed5128 <_gst_caps_free>)
    at gstminiobject.c:133
#1  0x76ed57b4 in gst_caps_init (caps=0x28600) at gstcaps.c:209
#2  gst_caps_new_empty () at gstcaps.c:239
#3  0x76ed58f8 in gst_caps_new_empty_simple (media_type=0x110b4 "application/x-rtp") at gstcaps.c:282
#4  0x00010bbc in main ()
```

I don't know if this can help, but I'm working on a Raspberry PI 3 (raspbian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761448) with Segmentation fault in `gst_mini_object_init()`. According to [this comment](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761448#c2) you should call `gst_init()` before using Gstreamer.

Did you call `gst_init()` before using Gstreamer API ?

Comment: I was doing it after (I'm so stupid ^^). Now I have another issue with `g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.udpsrc), "port", 5000, "caps", caps, NULL);` : `strchr() at ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv6/strchr.S : No such file or directory`

Comment: See [Segmentation fault with g_object_set / strchr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614067/segmentation-fault-with-g-object-set-strchr)