# Segmentation fault with g_object_set / strchr

Tags: c, gstreamer, raspbian, strchr

This line get me a **segmentation fault** :

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.udpsrc), "port", 5000, "caps", caps, NULL);
```

where

- `data.udpsrc = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "source");`
- `caps = gst_caps_new_empty_simple("application/x-rtp");`

Here's the output with gdb :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strchr () at ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv6/strchr.S:28
28  ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv6/strchr.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strchr () at ../ports/sysdeps/arm/armv6/strchr.S:28
#1  0x76e618d8 in g_param_spec_pool_lookup () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#2  0x76e5c6a4 in g_object_set_valist () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#3  0x76e5d00c in g_object_set () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00010dc4 in main ()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `g_object_set(data.udpsrc, "port", 5000, "caps", caps, NULL);`

Comment: I get the same output with and without G_OBJECT (seen in [Your first application on Gstreamer website](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html))

Comment: One of the pointer is NULL when it's expected not to be.

Comment: @0andriy I think `NULL` is ok. It is used as "terminator" of parameters on a variable arguments function.

Comment: Is it https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740191 ?

Comment: What is your Gstreamer version ? Can you update to latest version of Gstreamer ?

Comment: I was in 1.4.4, I'm compiling sources of gstreamer and plugins to 1.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Bug 740191](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740191). You need to update Gstreamer to 1.4.5 version at least.